# Why are all the strings I read ending up equal when I print them?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and there is a question in the book.

> Q: Write a program that defines a vector of pointers to strings. Read the vector,
>   printing each string and its corresponding size.

Code:

```
vector<string*> v;
string str;
cout<<"Enter your string:"<<endl;

while(cin >> str)                            // input 
{
          string *ps=&str;
          v.push_back(ps);
}

vector<string*>::iterator iter=v.begin();
while( iter!=v.end())                         // output
   cout<< **iter++<<" "<<(**iter).size()<<endl;
```

When I input "a sd fgh", I expect the output to be "a 1; sd 2; fgh 3"; but the output is "fgh 3; fgh 3; fgh 3."   Anyone know where is going wrong?

Comment: Your pointers are all pointing to the same variable, which you reuse.

Answer (score 3):

You get the same output because all your string point to the same place - namely, your `str` variable. You should create new strings using the buffer `str`'s data, like this:

```
std::string *ps = new string(str);
```

After you do that, don't forget to delete the strings that you allocated by calling `delete ptr` on each string pointer at the end of your function, when you no longer need the strings.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to vote up.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a clue: `std::string *ps = &str` is a very bad idea. Each pointer will need its own memory.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your help! Sorry, don't have enough 'reputation' to vote up.